# adding a column in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-manipulation

I would like to add an ID column to a data set using Shiny. And this ID column can be as long as the dataset `dat$my.ID <- (max(dat$ID) + 1):(max(dat$ID) + nrow(dat))` and should not limit the user who is entering a starting ID number. many thanks in advance.

#### ui.r

```
 navbarPage(
  title = 'Benvenuti',
  tabPanel('read.me', column(3,
                             
                             h3("Daily Data Manipulation"),
                          
                             h3("title1"),
                             tags$a("Upload data.xlsx")
  )),
  
  tabPanel(title = "title2", 
           sidebarPanel( width = 2, fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                                              accept = c(".xlsx")),
                         numericInput("ID", "enter the id number to increment", THERE SHOULD BE NO LIMIT IN MIN AND MAX )
           ), 
           
           mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "mytable"))
  ) )
```

#### server.r

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ########################################
  ### title1
  ########################################  
  
  data.Consenso <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(!is.null(inFile)) {
      readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
      #read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
    }
  })
  
  
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    
    dat <- data.Consenso()
    if(!is.null(dat))
    {
      dat$Tipo <- 3
      dat$my.ID <- (max(dat$ID) + 1):(max(dat$ID) + nrow(dat)) 
      dat
    }
  }) 
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Made changes in `ui`: `tabPanel(title = "title2",...`
and in `server`: `starting_id <- input$ID` takes the input from the user and  makes a sequence of IDs starting from the user input and incrementing by 1.

#### ui.r

```
library(shiny)

navbarPage(
  title = 'Benvenuti',
  tabPanel('read.me', column(
    3,
    
    h3("Daily Data Manipulation"),
    
    h3("title1"),
    tags$a("Upload data.xlsx")
  )),
  
  tabPanel(
    title = "title2",
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file', accept = c(".xlsx")),
      numericInput(
        "ID",
        "Enter the starting ID number:",
        value = 1,
        min = -Inf,
        max = Inf
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "mytable"))
  )
)
```

#### server.r

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data.Consenso <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (!is.null(inFile)) {
      readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    }
  })
  
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    dat <- data.Consenso()
    if (!is.null(dat)) {
      dat$Tipo <- 3
      starting_id <- input$ID
      dat$my.ID <- starting_id:(starting_id + nrow(dat) - 1)
      dat
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate <3